# What are the best blogs for submitting new startups?

Tags: seo, blog, backlinks, articles, website-review

There are some blogs where user can submit their start-ups for a review. Among them **[TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/)**, **ReadWriteWeb**, **[StartupTunes](http://startuptunes.com)**, **The Next Web** etc are common.

But what are others we can try submitting our start-ups for a review. More blogs mean more reviews and more quality SEO backlinks. So, share more quality start-up review blogs here and help us all.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you focus on getting featured on the biggest blogs out there (such as TechCrunch, ReadWriteWeb, Startup Tunes and The Next Web).

Once they write about you — all the other ones will just come along.